# Swift send messages without message composer

Tags: ios, swift

Can I send a iMessage or simple message without using the `MFMessageComposeViewController`?

Comment: add your efforts as well so that others can help you sort out

Comment: I would like to send messages without using the  MFMessageComposeViewController, it's only an idea, i have done nothing. For example: my app should send message by tapping a button that i have created with a preset text

Answer (score 1):

No, to the best of my knowledge, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, its to prevent privacy issues. Similarly, you can't send text messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Objective-C code on Swift project. SO try use "Mail2Core" 3rd party framework. You need to configure your mail using their framework locally and then that framework allows you to send mails without apple's MFMailComposerController. http://libmailcore.com check this link for more info.

Comment: thank you but i'm looking for imessage or message. Do you know something like Mail2Core for messages?

Comment: I'm not sure for messaging is there any such kind of option. But I know that there are some 3rd party API's which will give you their API to use and you can use them like normal web service calls and that 3rd party API will take care of sending message. This might be a cost effective.